# Android Spinner - Custom Background

Tags: android, background, custom-controls, spinner

A defined a spinner in my XML file like so:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/spinnerbackground"
    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp" />
```

The background loads correctly, however the text representing the selected item is aligned fully to the left. The default spinner however has the text offset from the left by a small amount.

Does anyone know the code or XML I can use to replicate the effect of offsetting the item display text?

Answer (score 2):

To make custom spinner background according to your textstyle you can use my code that I have used in one of my projects.

Inside **string.xml** Write:

```
   <string-array name="spinner_array_environtment">
        <item>Test</item>
        <item>Production</item>
    </string-array>
```

Inside your **MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spinner_environment;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                spinner_environment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerview);
adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,              R.array.spinner_array_environtment,R.layout.spinner_phone);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spinner_environment.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Inside **spinner_phone.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="#4C4646" />
```

try this out. Hope it will help you.